# Metrics for service calls using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, logging, metrics, resttemplate

I use Spring's `RestTemplate` to connect to a third-party RESTful API. I set the connect and read timeouts programatically in a custom extension of the `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` class:

```
protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) throws IOException {
    connection.setReadTimeout(loadReadTimeout());
    connection.setConnectTimeout(loadConnectionTimeout());

    super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);
}
```

My questions are:

- My assumption is that the read timeout does not include deserialization of the returned (JSON) response data. Is that correct?
- I need to obtain some metrics for these calls - ie - how long do we take to connect, how long to read the response, etc. Is there a built-in facility to log this information - eg - could I add a specific Log4j configuration to capture this information?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at Sprint Boot Metrics or does it not suit what you are after? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html

Comment: Thanks Steve. That might work if I could add that in but my hands are tied somewhat. I was hoping to simply add a log4j rule to target some logging statements which I was hoping existed in RestTemplate code. As it is, I think we will have to use Wily or similar to analyse the calls.